# making a function for searching movies by genre + txt file - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make function for searching movies by genre, so when I input name of genre it is suppose to print out all movies with that genre. But I have a problem, in my txt file, for example, I have (One flew over cuckoo's nest|**Drama**|133|Milos Forman|Jack Nicholson|USA|1975|"Description of the movie"...).  I splited it with "|" and genre is by index on [1] position. But I have also have movies with 2 different genres, for example,(Matrix|**Action,Sci-fi**|136|Lana and Lilly Wachowski|Keanu Reeves|USA|1999|"Description of the movie"...)
Now, If I input "Drama" it'll print out all of the movies that have "Drama" on index[1], but if I input, for example, "Action" it won't print out Matrix because Matrix has 2 genres (where program actually sees 1) so I have to input both of them with comma between them. 
I want to make program which, even if your movie has 2 genres and by inputing only 1 of them, your program will recognize it and print that movie out. (I tried spliting section "genre" with " , " but its list index out of range because not every movie has " , " in genre section)

```
list_movie = []

def movies_list():
    with open("film.txt","r") as f:
        all_h = ["name","genre","lasting","director","main role","country","year","desc"]
        for r in f.readlines():
            dicct = {}
            bla = r.strip().split("|")
            count = 0
            for i in bla:
                dicct[all_h[count]] = i
                count += 1
            list_movie.append(dicct)
movies_list()

def genre():
    x=False
    genres = input("Input genre: ")
    for r in list_movie:
        if r["genre"] == genres:
            print()
            print("Movie name: ", r["name"])
            print("Genre: ", r["genre"])
            print("Lasting: ",r["lasting"],"minutes")
            print("Director: ",r["director"])
            print("Main role: ",r["main role"])
            print("Country: ",r["country"])
            print("Year: ",r["year"])
            print("-------------------------------")
            x=True
    if x==True:
        print()
    else:
        print()
        print("No movie was found. ")
        print()
genre()
```

I made a function where I put all parts of the file in dict and then in list so I don't have to open file everytime I need something from that file. 
I also tried with going "if any..." but it goes for one letter so it don't work aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if genres in r['genre']:
    ...